# Avoid browsers default behavior required inputs

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

What I want to do is avoid browsers to show a tooltip when I try to submit a form that contains empty inputs. I'm validating with a plugin, and when I don't want to have two tooltips saying basically the same thing.

Comment: Please speficy, in the question itself, which code you are using (your own code and reference to any library you are using) and explain which tooltip you are referring to.

Comment: I'm Using KendoUI, specifically the validator plugin, and everything is okay, but I don't want to see those tooltips that Firefox or Chrome puts there.

Answer (score 1):

On the form you can add the `novalidate` attribute:

```
<form novalidate>
  <input required/>
</form>
```

Comment: In XHTML attribute minimization is forbidden. You would need to write `novalidate="novalidate"` and `required="required"`.

Comment: He is most likely using HTML5, AFAIK form validation isn't supported in XHTML

Comment: You are right, my apologies. I've been working so much using `XHTML` that I have this "reflex" of writing "XML well-formed" code.

Comment: There's no way, because I'm using KendoUI Validate, and it requires the require attribute and if I add novalidate attribute KendoUI Validate doesn't work really well.

Answer (score 0):

since there is a custom validation method its better to simply remove the `required` attribute from the `input`s rather having `required` inputs and a `novalidate` form.

a simple `novalidate` form does not guarantee compatibility with whatever the custom validation is and is just adding unnecessary complexity.